# Database design circular reference / potential inconsistency

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-normalization

I cannot come up with a way to get rid of this potential inconsistency:

Consider these 4 entities:

```
     CUSTOMERS  >----------------   LOCATIONS
      id                             id
      name                           name
      loc_id           
                                       |
       |                               |
       |                               |
       |                               |
       /\                              /\

      ORDERS   >------------------   PRODUCTS           
       c_id                           id
       p_id                           name
                                      loc_id
```

Each CUSTOMER has a LOCATION (id:"3", name:"US")

Each CUSTOMER orders many PRODUCTS, and each PRODUCT can be bought by many CUSTOMERS (those transactions are stored in the ORDERS table)

Each PRODUCT is only available to CUSTOMERS with the same LOCATION
("US" customers have access to “US” products)

### Problem:

I want to make a **product** only available to **customers** in "US”, so I insert a **product** with loc_id "3" (US).

The problem arises when I insert a **customer** with a loc_id "2" (EU) and create an **order** for that same **product**. I end up with a **customer** in one **LOCATION** which **ordered** a **product** available in a different **LOCATION**. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: It sounds like you need a trigger.

Comment: See my answer to [How to apply complex constraints to a database table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571843/how-to-apply-complex-constraints-to-a-database-table-in-mysql/42593347#42593347). However, your case probably requires that a customer's reputation level has to be greater than or equal to the product's reputation level, rather than just equal to. That requires a trigger.

Comment: @reaanb I just need them to match. I'm going to have to take some time to analyze your link, but from what I'm seeing, I could add replvl_id foreign keys to my ORDERS table which reference CUSTOMERS and PRODUCTS, and with a compound key enforce my requirement. Am I on the right track?

Comment: @Danbisso Yes, but with two compound keys.

Comment: The case for reputations equal is a faq. Google my comments about googling many versions of your question. You say in a comment that that is what you want. That is not what is in your question. Please edit you question to actually ask the question that you are trying to ask. (Comments are not for clarifications.)

Comment: @philipxy fair enough. Changed it to Location so that an equality check is assumed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply complex constraints to a database table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571843/how-to-apply-complex-constraints-to-a-database-table-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

> *The problem arises when I insert a customer with a loc_id "2" (EU) and create an order for that same product. I end up with a customer with in one LOCATION which ordered a product in a different LOCATION. Is there any way to avoid this?*

There's two ways to add this restriction. In your schema, or in your [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

In the schema you'd probably use a trigger on the orders table to ensure that the customer location and product location are the same.

In the model you'd add logic to your orders model to validate that the customer location and product location are the same before creating an order. And you'd ensure that everything which creates orders is using the model, not making SQL queries willy-nilly. You want this for other maintenance reasons also.

Where to put it? Model or schema? My answer is the model. Here's my thinking...

## Schema is for data integrity. Model is for business rules.

Corollary: "business rules" include most data validation.

"Customers and orders have to have the same location" is a *business rule*. It's a restriction defined by the business, and it can change at any time.

In contrast something like "every product must have a valid location" or "you can't delete a product that has orders" are *data integrity* issues. If `products.loc_id` is `null` or points to a row of locations that does not exist, bad things happen. This is what things like `not null` and `references` and `cascade` are for.

Business rules change all the time, so you want a solution that is quick and easy to change.

Schemas are expensive and risky to change. Any change can potentially affect everything which uses the database. Triggers are opaque and complex. SQL is also limited in what sort of validations it can do. Checking equality is one thing, but could it check if a URL is valid? That a word isn't a swear word? With limitations like these, you wind up with pressure to split validation and business rules between the schema and the model risking interference and confusion.

In contrast, the model is easy to change and test. It can react quickly to the whims of business rules. Programming languages are better suited to the full range of data validations, and many model libraries come with rich validation functions. Some will even translate these automatically into schema constraints for you.

## Business rules and data validation get complicated

In addition, business rules are, as far as the data is concerned, an arbitrary external restriction. If you put it in the schema, everything which interacts with the data must have this restriction: ***no exceptions***. This means any business rules you put in the schema must handle all possibilities.

Business rules tend to start out simple but become more complex over time. Triggers and constraints are not designed for complexity. Putting your business rules in the schema has a tendency to restrict what is possible for your business simply because the rules cannot be easily expressed as a trigger.

In contrast models are written in programming languages which handle complexity very well. Maybe US & Canada need to be grouped? Or EU countries? Maybe some customers paid extra for international shipping? A model written in any decent programming language can handle all this extra complexity.

## What if not everything uses the model? Stored procedures.

These days we tend to write the model and use tools which then writes the schema for us. And it's expected that all interaction with the database will be via the model. But that isn't always the case. If the data validation is in the model, what about things which are using the database which aren't the model?

My first answer is: consider not doing that. If heterogeneous systems need access to the data, consider a [micro-service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices) to act as an abstraction layer over the database. Then other systems needing to use the data interact with it via a well defined API. This avoids everyone grabbing at the database willy-nilly and never knowing who is doing what with the data.

If you can't do that, consider a hybrid approach with stored procedures. Write stored procedures as part of your model. They handle interacting with the database and do all the [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) work. In your case you'd write a `new_order` stored procedure which does all the validation the model would do. Then anyone interacting with the database would use the stored procedures rather than writing their own queries.

Many databases even allow stored procedures written in other languages allowing you the full range of their flexibility. Unfortunately MySQL does not. If you're just starting your progress, consider switching to a more powerful database such as PostgreSQL.

## Conclusion

The sort of data validation you're talking about is a business rule. Business rules change all the time, and they tend to get more complex than triggers and constraints can handle. They belong in the model where they're easier to change and more powerful validation tools.

And be sure to have a model.