# Enforcing foreign key constraints based on additional column

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, foreign-keys

I have the following business rules:

1. An account can have zero or more licenses.
2. Each license has an unique guid.
3. Each license is preassigned to a given account.
4. All installations belong to a given account.
5. All commercial_installations require a license.
6. No two commercial_installations can use the same license.
7. A commercial_installation can be deleted and the license can be then used on a new commercial_installation.
8. A commercial_installation can only use a license which has been assigned to the installation's account.

**How can I enforce the last rule?** *A commercial_installation can only use a license which has been assigned to the installation's account.*  Or in other words, for a given guid to be stored in `commercial_installations`, `licenses.accounts_id` must equal `installations.accounts_id`. See sample data at the bottom.

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accounts (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  otherData VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS licenses (
  guid CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  accounts_id INT NOT NULL,
  otherData VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (guid),
  INDEX fk_licenses_accounts1_idx (accounts_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_licenses_accounts1
    FOREIGN KEY (accounts_id)
    REFERENCES accounts (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS installations (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  accounts_id INT NOT NULL,
  otherData VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  INDEX fk_installations_accounts1_idx (accounts_id ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_installations_accounts1
    FOREIGN KEY (accounts_id)
    REFERENCES accounts (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS open_installations (
  installations_id INT NOT NULL,
  otherData VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (installations_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_open_installations_installations1
    FOREIGN KEY (installations_id)
    REFERENCES installations (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS commercial_installations (
  installations_id INT NOT NULL,
  licenses_guid CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  otherData VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (installations_id),
  UNIQUE INDEX fk_commercial_installations_licenses1_idx (licenses_guid ASC),
  CONSTRAINT fk_commercial_installations_installations1
    FOREIGN KEY (installations_id)
    REFERENCES installations (id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_commercial_installations_licenses1
    FOREIGN KEY (licenses_guid)
    REFERENCES licenses (guid)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Given the following sample data:

- `b5060518-f87e-4acc-82c8-adb5750685a9` and `d6f23460-0d77-400e-ae96-13f436e40245` can only exist in `commercial_installations` where `commercial_installations.id` is `1` or `2`.
- Similarly, `8739ef62-7fff-4913-81de-3d00e8f50ecb` for `3`.
- Similarly, `36cc0787-5cb9-4c3a-b79d-1dcfb83d2794` for `4`.

accounts

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Account 1 |
|  2 | Account 2 |
|  3 | Account 3 |
|  4 | Account 4 |
+----+-----------+
```

licenses

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------+
|                 guid                 | accounts_id |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+
| b5060518-f87e-4acc-82c8-adb5750685a9 |           1 |
| d6f23460-0d77-400e-ae96-13f436e40245 |           1 |
| 36cc0787-5cb9-4c3a-b79d-1dcfb83d2794 |           2 |
| 8739ef62-7fff-4913-81de-3d00e8f50ecb |           3 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+
```

installations

```
+----+-------------+
| id | accounts_id |
+----+-------------+
|  1 |           1 |
|  2 |           1 |
|  3 |           3 |
|  4 |           2 |
+----+-------------+
```

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I currently do, but for `guid` only.   I could either make `licenses` primary key composite `guid-accounts_id` or add a a second constraint `commercial_installations.accounts_id` references `accounts.id`.  But if I do, there is no enforcement that `commercial_installations.accounts_id` is the same as `installations.accounts_id`, and I cannot add such a constraint as `installations.accounts_id` already references `acccounts.id`.  And around and around I go...

Comment: "But if I do, there is no enforcement that `commercial_installations.accounts_id` is the same as `installations.accounts_id`, and I cannot add such a constraint as installations.accounts_id already references acccounts.id. And around and around I go" True now i look better into it... i think you need to use a BEFORE INSERT trigger that checks if `commercial_installations.accounts_id` is the same as `installations.accounts_id` by selecting also into licences and account.. Can you add some example records for the tables?

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I added example data.  I was thinking of a trigger.  I hesitate as whenever I do such, I need to make it throw some custom exception which no matter how well I document, I forget about it down the road and put myself on a goose chance.  If a trigger, how would you recommend implementing?  Thanks

Comment: After looking more into your datamodel. i also wondering why there is a `commercial_installations`  table it looks not needed. Besides "commercial" sounds more like a metadata (type) to me. Using metadata as table name is more or less a SQL anti pattern.. i would drop the `commercial_installations` table and add a `installation_id` field to the licenses table also removes the need for storing the guid twice.. Unless the table `commercial_installations` is meant as Inheritance  from the table `installations` to bad MySQL does not support Inheritance like PostgreSQL does

Comment: @RaymondNijland - *"Besides "commercial" sounds more like a metadata (type) to me. Using metadata as table name is more or less a SQL anti pattern."* hmmm, there's a well-established convention of modellng sub-types with a foreign key arc across multiple child tables, and it seems to me that the implementation of INSTALLATION types fits this pattern. This has to be better than a single table with complex check constraints enforcing rules for different types of installation. As indeed you acknowledge with your mention of *inheritance*.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  I don't know about inheritance and PostgreSQL, but it is a simple super/sub type architecture which I suppose is inheritance of sorts.  I use this pattern often for this type of situation and it works well.

Comment: Sorry but I have to ask: is this some kind of excercise? Looking at your profile I somehow doubt it, but since there is a solution (the one Raymond proposed, adding the installation_id to licenses, and two foreign keys) that both fulfills the requirements to the letter (including that you have to actually delete a commercial installation before reassigning the license) and, indicative for theory questions, is problematic in reality (as you e.g. would usually mark an entry as deleted instead of actually deleting it), in case it *is* an excercise, that would most likely be the correct answer.

Comment: See my answer to [How to apply complex constraints to a database table in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42571843/how-to-apply-complex-constraints-to-a-database-table-in-mysql/42593347#42593347)

Comment: @Solarflare  Raymond's solution does not change the outcome.  Licenses are created before an installation and are preassigned to a given account, so accountsId must exist in licenses and should reference the accounts table.  I suppose I could add an installationsId to licenses, but still have the same issue needing to enforce only installations of a given account are inserted.

Comment: I meant something like this: add installation_id (nullable) to licenses, make it unique and remove the guid from commercial_installations. Add a foreign key from commercial_installations to licenses.installation_id. Add a foreign key from licenses(account_id, installation_id) to installations (the parent one, enforces 8). To add a commercial installation: add a stub id to installations, update some row in license with that id, add the id to commercial_installation. Unless I missed something, this should enforce your rules (although it doesn't seem very practical/extendible).

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can enforce it in the logic of your application, but I guess you want to do it at the database level.

The only option I see here is to add triggers for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations. Normal foreign keys will not do this for you.

And I like this question, since I've had this problem before and didn't really take the time of formally asking about it here in SO.

Comment: I am currently enforcing in the application, but yeah would rather do so at the database level.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply propagate `account_ID` to `commercial_installations`. It also takes few more *unique constraints*, marked as SK (superkey, superset of a key) to be used as targets for FKs in the model.

```
accounts {account_ID, account_name}
      PK {account_ID}


licenses {license_ID, account_ID}
      PK {license_ID}
      SK {license_ID, account_ID}     
      FK {account_ID} REFERENCES accounts {account_ID}


installations {installation_ID, account_ID, installation_TYPE}
      PK {installation_ID}
      SK {installation_ID, account_ID}     
      FK {account_ID} REFERENCES accounts {account_ID}


open_installations {installation_ID}
      PK {installation_ID}
      FK {installation_ID} REFERENCES installations {installation_ID}


commercial_installations {installation_ID, account_ID, license_ID}
     PK {installation_ID}
     AK {license_ID}              

     FK1 {installation_ID, account_ID} 
         REFERENCES installations {installation_ID, account_ID}

     FK2 {license_ID, account_ID} 
         REFERENCES licenses {license_ID, account_ID}
```

```
Notes:

All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
SK = Superkey      (Unique)
AK = Alternate Key (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```